# Переход назад при AJAX

Tags: php, javascript

Есть страница со списком товаром, переход по страницам реализован аяксом, если мы нажимаем на товар, то он открывается в этой же вкладке. И потом, когда мы нажимаем на кнопку назад, чтобы вернутся к списку товаров, мы попадаем на первую страницу. Как можно реализовать, чтобы мы попадали на ту же страницу с которой ушли? Например, долистали до 5, открыли товар и вернулись так же на пятую?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у Вас же где то сохраняется номер текущей страницы? если так, то просто когда нажимаете назад сделайте переход так же само ajax и передайте параметр (номер текущей страницы). если так не получается, то объясните всем как именно через ajax у вас работает переход по страницам, чтоб все поняли и могли что то подсказать

Comment: Переход работает так: мы отправляем аякс-запрос по ссылке, которая содержится в номере страницы, и оттуда часть с товарами вставляем вместо текущей части с товарами.

Comment: запоминайте номер страницы (например в переменную js), и при переходе назад с страницы товара на список товаров, то открывайте ajax-ом так же само как и при переходе на следующую страницу, но номер страницы уже будет Ваша сохраненная переменная

Comment: Нет, на страницу товара мне не нужен аякс, может якорем как-то сделать?

Comment: Копайте в сторону `window.history` из `html 5`. Вам нужно использовать `history.pushState` при кликах на кнопках навигации.

Answer (score 1):

На событие `"click"` пагинации повесил `history.pushState(null, null, href);`, где `href` - сслыка, по которой идёт AJAX - запрос.

Comment: Учтите только что в старых браузерах вам все равно придется мириться с тем, что возвращаться будет на первую страницу. Если проект серьезный, то в качестве варианта могу предложить вам для старых браузеров сделать механизм перехода по страничкам без `ajax`. И для `SEO` вроде как хорошо будет, хотя тут я не уверен.

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделаю!